# flutter "material_color_utilities" The update of the dependent package is failing

Tags: flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-pub

### C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
No dependencies changed.
1 package has newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

can you help me with this

### PS C:\Users\Atacan\StudioProjects\untitled> dart pub upgrade --major-versions
Resolving dependencies... (1.2s)
material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
No dependencies changed.
1 package has newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.